# Connect to pinterest with R

Tags: r

I want to connect to a Pinterest app I created with the httr package. Therefore I use the `oauth2.0_token()` function. 
The problem is: It redirects the browser to `http://localhost:1410`
But Pinterest just allows **https** redirect URIs. 
So how can I make httr use https instead as the redirect URI?

My code so far:

```
pinterest <- oauth_endpoint(
  authorize = "https://api.pinterest.com/oauth",
  access = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/token")  

myapp <- oauth_app(app_name, client_id, NULL)



#scope <- NULL
pi_oauth <- oauth2.0_token(pinterest, myapp,scope=scope,type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",cache=FALSE)
```

Comment: JulianHi I decided to delete my answer as it isn't in fact a complete answer. I'll put time into finding an answer. :-) I hope that is ok. My sense is no answer yet published will attract more interest. Take care